# C# delete files based on text file

Tags: c#

Hy,

I have a FilesToDelete.txt file filled with file paths like:

```
C:\Users\Me\Pics\file01.png
C:\Users\Me\Pics\file03.png
C:\Users\Me\Pics\file15.png
etc...
```

How can I delete these files with C#?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [File.ReadAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) and [File.Delete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple process would be to loop over each entry in the text file and delete one at a time.

```
string fileName = @"C:\file_with_paths_to_delete.txt";
    var files = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    foreach(string file in files)
        File.Delete(file);
```